# How do I make a tuple from sqlite DB into unicode for changing text color?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, tuples

My goal is to change the text color by accessing color parameters stored in a database. I am able to get the colors to work when I define them manually. However, when I try to pull them from the database the colors aren't working. I feel like I'm not converting the tuples correctly as a usable unicode, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

##### Modules to Import ######
import database
import sqlite3

##### Connect To Databases #####
conn = sqlite3.connect('project.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def workingCode():
    class bcolors:
        status_read = '\033[97m'
        status_good = '\033[32m'
        status_warning = '\033[33m'
        status_bad = '\033[31m'
        status_reset = '\033[0m'

    print "This is how " + bcolors.status_read + "I want the " + bcolors.status_good \
        + "text to be " + bcolors.status_warning + " printed " + bcolors.status_bad \
        + " on the screen."+ bcolors.status_reset


def nonWorkingCode():   
    c.execute ('SELECT * FROM text_colors')
    text_colors = c.fetchone()

    class bcolors:
        status_read, status_good, status_warning, status_bad, task_start, task_success, \
        lighting_text  =text_colors [:7]

    print "Instead " + bcolors.status_read + "I get " + bcolors.status_good + \
    "a whole " + bcolors.status_warning + " bunch of this " + bcolors.status_bad + " garbage."


workingCode()
nonWorkingCode()
```

[image: output of the code listed above]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the finished working code I just spent 30 minutes on
let me know if you have any questions. JP:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

sqlite_file = 'project.db'


def workingCode():

    class bcolors:
        status_read = '\033[97m'
        status_good = '\033[32m'
        status_warning = '\033[33m'
        status_bad = '\033[31m'
        status_reset = '\033[0m'

    print("This is how " + bcolors.status_read + "I want the " + bcolors.status_good \
        + "text to be " + bcolors.status_warning + " printed " + bcolors.status_bad \
        + " on the screen."+ bcolors.status_reset)


def nonWorkingCode():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Create text_colors table
    create_table("text_colors")

    # then populate text_colors table
    populate_tbl("text_colors")

    c.execute('SELECT STATUS, COLOR FROM text_colors')

    status_color_mappings = c.fetchall()

    status_color_dictionary = dict(status_color_mappings)

    print(status_color_dictionary)

    class dictColors:
        status_read = str(status_color_dictionary['status_read'])
        status_good = str(status_color_dictionary['status_good'])
        status_warning = str(status_color_dictionary['status_warning'])
        status_bad = str(status_color_dictionary['status_bad'])
        status_reset = str(status_color_dictionary['status_reset'])

    print("Instead " + dictColors.status_read + "I get " + dictColors.status_good + "a whole " +
          dictColors.status_warning + " bunch of this " + dictColors.status_bad + " garbage." +
          " on the screen."+ dictColors.status_reset)


def create_table(ptbl):
    """ Assemble DDL (Data Definition Language) Table Create statement and build
        sqlite3 db table

    Args:
        string: new db table name.

    Returns:
        Status string, '' or 'SUCCESS'.
    """
    retval = ''
    sqlCmd = ''
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
        c = conn.cursor()

        if ptbl == 'text_colors':
            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + ' (STATUS TEXT, COLOR TEXT)'
        else:
            pass

        if sqlCmd != '':
            c.execute(sqlCmd)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

        retval = 'SUCCESS'

    except Error as e:

        retval = 'FAIL'
        print(e)

    return retval


def populate_tbl(p_fml_tbl):
    """

    :param p_fml_tbl:
    :return:
    """
    retval = ''

    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('INSERT INTO ' + p_fml_tbl + ' (STATUS, COLOR) VALUES (?, ?)', ('status_read', '\033[97m'))
        c.execute('INSERT INTO ' + p_fml_tbl + ' (STATUS, COLOR) VALUES (?, ?)', ('status_good', '\033[32m'))
        c.execute('INSERT INTO ' + p_fml_tbl + ' (STATUS, COLOR) VALUES (?, ?)', ('status_warning', '\033[33m'))
        c.execute('INSERT INTO ' + p_fml_tbl + ' (STATUS, COLOR) VALUES (?, ?)', ('status_bad', '\033[31m'))
        c.execute('INSERT INTO ' + p_fml_tbl + ' (STATUS, COLOR) VALUES (?, ?)', ('status_reset', '\033[0m'))

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        retval = 'SUCCESS'

    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return retval


if __name__ == '__main__':
    workingCode()
    nonWorkingCode()
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! So if I am looking at this correctly, you're essentially unpacking the contents from the table as a string? And that is what allows it to function as code and not plain test? Thank you again!

Comment: Yup, it was a little tricky and took a bit of time haha. Thank you so much. Best regards!

Comment: Dude, I can't say thank you enough. This code really helped me get my project going, but it also really helped me understand sqlite a lot better.